# How to join two tables and make the matching columns from table two to appear on one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that look kinda like this:

```
   User table                   Roles table
   [id][name]                   [Userid][value]
    1   Tom                        1       3
    2   Bob                        1       4
                                   2       3
```

I was wondering how to get the result to look like this:

```
[id][name][userid1][value1][userid2][value2] 
 1   Tom     1        3        1        4
 2   Bob     2        3
```

when i ask for the matching values in the roles table.
Is there a way to do this without having to use a cursor?

Comment: Using pivot to resolve stuff but it is need fixed column

Comment: Why does Bob have value1=4 and not value1=3 in your example?

Comment: cause i misstyped. didnt notice sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to number each row for each user then you can use aggregation functions (i.e. `MAX()`) to include multiple values in the same row:

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.name,
       r.value1,
       r.value2
FROM   users u
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (
         SELECT userid,
                MAX( CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN value END ) AS value1,
                MAX( CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN value END ) AS value2
         FROM   (
           SELECT userid,
                  value,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UserID
                                      ORDER BY value ) AS rn
           FROM   roles
         )
         GROUP BY userid
       ) r
       ON ( u.id = r.userid )
```

Comment: using this solution i would have to know how many columns that i need up front? am i understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes. While it is possible to do a [dynamic pivot on an unknown number of columns](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3Ap11_question_id:4843682300346852395) it usually requires dynamic sql and I expect it is not going to be very performant. It is also possible that your front-end (assuming you are not working in pure SQL) can transform the data and it will probably be better to look at that end rather than trying to do it through Oracle.